# AntiContainer JSON help requested

Tags: json, firefox, plugins

Where can I find a tutorial for writing [DownThemAll AntiContainer](https://bugs.downthemall.net/wiki/AntiContainer) plugins in JSON?

The [documentation](https://bugs.downthemall.net/wiki/AntiContainer/WritingPlugins) is confusing...

Comment: What is a downthemall anticontainer plugin?

Comment: @Pekka — It appears to be a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall-anticontainer/).

Comment: @Ben ah, down *them* all, I read "down the mall" :)

Comment: @Pekka — As did I, until I searched for "anticontainer". ;-)

Comment: I started trying to write a simple plugin for this, but I can't test it because when I try to install it in the anticontainer settings, nothing happens (it doesn't install), there definitely seems to be a bug regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that, five hours after you asked it, this question is already one of the [top ten Google results for "DownThemAll AntiContainer tutorial"](http://www.google.com/search?q=downthemall+anticontainer+tutorial), it seems unlikely that any more detailed tutorials exist.

Perhaps you can learn more by examining [the source code of existing plugins](https://github.com/nmaier/anticontainer/tree/master/plugins/) or by contacting one of the plugin authors, [nmaier](https://github.com/nmaier) and [poke](https://github.com/poke)?  (You need [a GitHub account](https://github.com/signup/free) to use the "message" feature.)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking:

This is a nice Wiki-Tutotrial about it https://github.com/downthemall/anticontainer/wiki/Writing-plugins

however, it does not explain the fine details, to grasp how this can be applied to a specific problem